# How can I edit/update environment variables using a run in postman button?

Tags: api, postman

I’m trying to use the run in postman button. I see instructions in the documentation (https://learning.postman.com/docs/publishing-your-api/run-in-postman/run-button-API/) about how to edit an existing environment. But I find it unclear how to implement the provided code.

I want my run in postman button to have different environment variables based on values sent from the page that the button is located on. Essentially editing the environment to have values based on the current values in the html.

Can anyone explain what this code in the documentation is doing and where it’s supposed to go (aka in the javascript or in a postman test)?

From postman documentation (https://learning.postman.com/docs/publishing-your-api/run-in-postman/run-button-API/):

**Update an environment's API keys:**

```
function () {


var stagingKey = document.getElementById('staging-key-input').value,
    productionKey = document.getElementById('production-key-input').value,
    preventOveride = true;
    runButtonIndex = 0,
    envData = {
      stagingKey: stagingKey,
      productionKey: productionKey
    };

  _pm('env.assign', 'API Keys', envData, preventOveride, runButtonIndex);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `env.assign` method updates an existing environment that you embed along with a collection in the Run in Postman button. You will need to invoke your anonymous function from the page that the button is located on.

I have [a code sample](https://github.com/loopDelicious/dynamic-rip-button) of creating a new environment (not editing an existing one), but the process is similar. In my example, the JavaScript function is executed when the HTML form is submitted using `onsubmit`.